# MacOS - tab completion to be case insensetive - terminal zsh

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, zsh

I'm a MacOS newbie, so please try to help me with idiot-proof answers.

I got a macbook pro from work. On the terminal, I want tab completions to ignore case-sensitive files / directories. i.e both cd Documents and cd documents should work.

Most answers that i found are related to .inputrc file, which i've created. but it didn't work. Opening the terminal, the header says '-zsh'. But i couldn't find any solution that is working.

How can I make it work? and again, idiot proof answers please. like step-by-step. assume i know nothing on MacOS system.

Comment: Found the answer here:
https://scriptingosx.com/2019/07/moving-to-zsh-part-5-completions/ with compinstall process.

Comment: Great! Now please _close_ your question or convert your comment to an _answer_ and accept it.

Answer (score 7):

Using macOS 12.3 I had the very same problem. None of the advice seemed to work for me. I referred to 'man zshcompsys' command and fixed it by adding one '' in 'completion'. Add code below to your zshrc config. (in my case the path is /etc/zshrc)

```
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
zstyle ':completion:\*' matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Za-z}'
```

Most of the answers mentioned ':completion:*' without \ which didn't work for me.
Hope this helps.

Comment: On my macOS 10.15.7 `':completion:*'` worked instead of `':completion:\*'`

Comment: I also had to use `':completion:*'` on macOS 13.2.1 and zsh 5.8.1.